# What is wavelength?

Tags: waves, wavelength

I know that wavelength is the distance between corresponding points of two consecutive waves. It is the distance over which a wave repeats its motion. But I am unable to understand what is actually wavelength? What does it really mean?  Is wavelength the length of medium over which one complete wave is formed?

Comment: @Swike  the case of light due to which we observe different color.

Comment: @Swike When waves from a rarer to denser medium its speed  decreases . The frequency remain the same so it means that the wavelength decreases and  we also know this formula: wave speed=frequency×wavelength

Comment: you should ad, what waves you mean, loud waves move faster in solid bodies than in air, light moves slower in matter  than in vacuum, Waterwaves move depending on the death of water and so on. in Water or on a string you can see the wavelength,

Comment: @Physics; @trula is saying correct.

Comment: @trula; @Vaibhav Pankhala I edited my question because i think  adding about changing speed is affecting the real thing which i want to know i.e. wavelength.

Comment: Wavelength is the length between, for example, the crests of a wave. It's as simple as that, nothing more to it.

Comment: @my2cts I know this thing but what i actually want to know is wavelength decreases or increases and that is the distance between crests increases or decreases or we can say the the length of a single wave increases of decreases but how does that happen? Does the number of molecules of the medium in a wave increases or decreases so the wavelength increaes or decrease?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is really too trivial.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because adding *"really"*/*"actually"* after (or before) the question doesn't change the question, neither does it change the answer.

Comment: @my2cts I have just voted to leave this question open because it is not as simple as people too used to unphysical, perfect, sinusoidal waves think.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a picture of some waves:

[image]

The wavelength is literally the distance between two peaks, or between two troughs, or any other corresponding points on successive waves, as I indicated in the image. If the waves are produced by a constant-frequency source, then the distance will be the same for any choice of location on the wave that you measure. (And for the case of waves propagating away from a point source, as in this image, you'd also want to measure further away from the source, where "near field" [as we call them in electromagnetics] effects have decayed away)

The wavelength is measured in meters (or millimeters or centimeters or kilometers) , because it is an actual distance in space.

Comment: Nanometers, picometers, femtometers, hectometers etc.

Comment: From your explanation it would seem that there is only one wavelength in a wave. This is not the case in general, but for trivial 1D sinusoidal waves. Real waves are not plane waves!

Comment: @GiorgioP My reading of the question is they’re just trying to get a conceptual understanding, and they’re not ready to start throwing around Bessel functions or spherical harmonics.

Answer (score 0):

Consider waves as means to transport energy. Then this follows quickly from the conservation of energy:

Easiest it's explained with a light wave, but a very similar argument can be made for other waves like in the oceans as well:

A a single photon of a light wave has the energy $E=h\nu=h \cdot \frac{c}{\lambda}$ with the frequency $\nu$, wave velocity $c$ and wavelength $\lambda$; $h$ is a constant (the Planck constant).

If we now change the velocity of propagation, (e.g. when moving from the upper atmosphere to the lower or into water; for light the reduction factor is indicated by refractive index), we must keep the energy constant. Then the only thing which can change besides the velocity $c$ is the wavelength $\lambda$ so that the quotient of $\frac{c}{\lambda}$ remains constant.

In water the velocity is a [function of water depth](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/watwav.html), so there a similar relation exists (even when the wave velocity as a function of depth is rather complicated).

Reality is a bit more complicated as you also have effects of [dispersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_(water_waves)) when you don't consider an infinitely long wave.

As to the question "what is wavelength": it is the distance between two maxima or two minima, the distance a whole period of the wave occupies at any given time - there's no other magic behind it. Speaking of a water wave: you take a photo of a water wave, you measure the distance between two wave crests, that's the wavelength. Strictly speaking you need an infinitely long wave; then it is the shortest extent of the spacial periodicity.

Comment: @planetmakef I completely understand your point but can you explain me what is actuallg wavelength?

Comment: it's exactly that what the word will make you believe: the periodicity length of a(n infinite) wave